# Excel: Populate cells with data from file names that use common naming convention

Tags: vba, excel, cmd, explorer

I have 1000+ files (mostly PDFs) that all follow a common naming convention, e.g.:

#### CA0001.02 Tax Return A-333 650.5ca 20140729.pdf

Each file has different information in its filename (the "CA number" is different, the "A-number" is different, the date is different, etc.).

**I want to create a spreadsheet so that I can manipulate the data that these file names contain**; in other words, take the 5 pieces of info listed in the filename and turn it into 5 columns in Excel.

In my research I've come across ways to insert the *Excel* filename into the current sheet, but that's not what I want. I want to insert the filenames of thousands of *other* files located elsewhere on the computer. My ideal solution would ensure that:

1. Each file gets its own row
2. Each field in the filename goes into the appropriate Excel column
3. Any filenames that are missing data wouldn't break the operation (e.g., if the date "20140729" wasn't at the end of the file, then the whole thing wouldn't break, it would just leave that cell empty and move to the next file).

I imagine this will require VBA or Command Prompt (and maybe something else?) but my skill with VBA is pretty weak. I would really appreciate any suggestions to get me started. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too generic for a simple answer. The following VBA function with some help from Google should get you started:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim FN As String, R As Integer
  R = 1
  FN = Dir("C:\*")
  Do While FN <> ""
    Cells(R, 1) = FN
    If InStr(FN, "CA") Then Cells(R, 2) = "This contains CA!"
    FN = Dir
    R = R + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: How can I help make it more specific? What questions do you have for me?

I'm not really sure how to make it more detailed beyond saying that I want "CA.0001.02" to go into cell A1, "Tax Return" into B1, "A-333" into C1, "650.5" into D1, and "20140709" into E1. And the next file would populate its info into row 2, and the next file into row 3, and so on.

Comment: Make it more specific by showing what you have tried. Your question is well formed, but it asks for a solution, not for help. Here you will find help for you to find your solution, but then you need to to the work.